# Component nested in more component not lose reference in change component

Tags: angular

i've 2 component with nested other components:

- `BacklogComponent`

```
...
<backlog-table>
  <ng-container expandedDetail>
    <manual-amount [maxValueFunction]="maxValue()"></manual-amount>
   </ng-container>
</backlog-table>
...
```

```
maxValue() {
  return (entity) => {
    console.log(this); // added for debug
    return subNumbers(entity.financeable, entity.financed);
  };
}
```

- `CollectionComponent`

```
...
<receivable-table>
  <ng-container expandedDetail>
    <manual-amount [maxValueFunction]="maxValue()"></manual-amount>
   </ng-container>
</receivable-table>
...
```

```
maxValue() {
  return (entity) => {
    return reconcileElement(entity.outstanding, entity.collected, entity.amount, entity.total);
  };
}
```

`ReceivableTableComponent` and `BacklogTableComponent` have same template with

```
...
<ng-content select="[expandedDetail]"></ng-content>
...
```

`ManualAmountComponent implements OnInit` and:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.expandedDetailService.entity$
  .subscribe((gotEntity: T) => {
    if (gotEntity) {
      this.element = gotEntity;
      this.maxValue = this.maxValueFunction(this.element);
    }
  });
}
```

Now, started app, i go to link for `CollectionComponent` and in console have

`CollectionComponent {...}`

Then i change page and go to `BacklogComponent`. In console added

`CollectionComponent {...}`

`BacklogComponent{...}`

Why my component `CollectionComponent` is not destroy? Nay, i add `ngOnDestroy` to `CollectionComponent` and when i change page it is call, but why `ManualAmountComponent` have reference to `CollectionComponent` when i call in `BacklogComponent`? (Obviously if I do the reverse i've in console

`BacklogComponent{...}`

`BacklogComponent{...}`

`CollectionComponent {...}`)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the same component in both the parent component.
It would have the reference because it maintains the cycle through out the application.

If you want to loose the reference of the previously binding component you need to use `ngOnDestroy` method in the `ManualAmountComponent` to reset the all the values that you want to get reinitialzed.

And here as you are subscribing the service in `ManualAmountComponent` you need to `unsubscribe()` it as well.

So you need to maintain the array of subscription in the nested component as shown below.

```
 subscriptions:Subscription[]=[]       
 ngOnInit() {
      this.subscriptions.push(this.expandedDetailService.entity$
      .subscribe((gotEntity: T) => {
        if (gotEntity) {
          this.element = gotEntity;
          this.maxValue = this.maxValueFunction(this.element);
        }
      });
     ) 
    }
 ngOnDestroy(){
  this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription)=>subscription.unSubscribe())
}
```

Comment: If this resolved the issue please verify it and upvote, so that other can use this.